# How to underline titles? (reStructuredText, Markdown, asciidoc style)

Tags: markup

Various plain-text markup languages: 
*reStructuredText, Markdown, asciidoc (others too)*,
use an underline to denote titles.

```
Chapter 1 Title
===============

Section 1.1 Title
-----------------

Subsection 1.1.1 Title
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Section 1.2 Title
-----------------

Chapter 2 Title
===============
```

Is there a convenient way add these in vim?

*add a character with a length matching the line above.*

Comment: It doesn't directly answer your question, but it's worth saying that some markup langs (e.g. Markdown) also support a leading `#` character instead for a level 1 heading, `##` for level 2, etc. That's how I write Markdown, and I find it clearer that way anyway.

Comment: @Andrew Ferrier, Im not using markdown & the question isnt specifically about markdown, its just an example of a markup that can use titles like this. I listed 3x different markups especially to avoid discussion on the specifics on any of the markup languages.

Comment: I understand. It was just an incidental comment for anyone who does. Your question is totally valid, I agree.

Answer (score 22):

A naïve approach (no plugins or scripting) would be <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>V</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>=</kbd>.

Explanation:

- <kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> duplicates the current line and puts the cursor on the lower line.
- <kbd>V</kbd> selects the second line in Visual Line mode.
- <kbd>r</kbd><kbd>=</kbd> replaces all characters on the line with the `=` character.

You can, of course, `:noremap` that keystroke sequence to your taste.

eg:

```
" Add Heading: Control-H
nnoremap <C-h> YpVr
```

...leaving off the last character so you can type in whichever you want for the title.

Comment: This is not naïve by any means.

Comment: @romainl it's only naive until you map it to something shorter I guess